# How to create list to track documents uploaded

Tags: workflow, document, library, checklist

I have two lists and a library that are connected together as follows:

Clients (List)>Deals (List)>Deal Files (Library)

In the Deal Files library, there is a Document type choice field with about 15 different types.  I am looking to create a list that would be a checklist that lists out each document type with the following fields: Uploaded (Yes/No), Date Uploaded (Date), Uploaded By (Person).

I envision a workflow that would trigger when a document is uploaded and update the Checklist based on the document type uploaded.

I would like to view the Checklist from a Deals (List) display form, like on a tabs view, so that you would see the following:

Doc Type   Uploaded   Uploaded Date    Uploaded By
Contract      No
OS            Yes        9/26/2016       John Smith

I know that is a lot of info, but does anyone have any thoughts on how to approach this?   I am really stumped.

Answer (score 0):

To start - create the "Deal Document Checklist" with following fields - Contract No, Doc Type , Uploaded (Yes/No), Date Uploaded (Date), Uploaded By (Person).

When new item gets created in Deals list, 15 items (depends on number of Doc Type) gets created in "Deal Document Checklist" list with Uploaded = False.

Once when relevant user uploads document in "Deal Files (Library)", it will trigger workflow to update the item in "Deal Document Checklist" based on matching values like Contract No & Doc Type. Values that will be updated will - Date Uploaded, Uploaded By and Uploaded = Yes.

For view purpose, add the "Deal Document Checklist" view on Deals (List) display form. Make connection with Deal item and "Deal Document Checklist" to send row of data to "Deal Document Checklist" to filter out items.

Comment: if the solution works out ... mark as answer :)